# Is this 'as' a conjunction?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis

I guess ‘as’ is a conjunction. If then, is as-clause an adjective clause that modifies ‘Muggle money’?

> There was a train to London in five minutes' time. Hagrid, who didn't understand 'Muggle money,' **as he called it**, gave the bills to Harry so he could buy their tickets.

Comment: A conjunction connects two parallel, similar function phrases. 'he called it' is subordinate and not parallel to 'muffle money'.

Comment: Or even "Muggle money". So what is ***as***, then? MW gives [several viable alternatives](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as), including conjunction, pronoun and preposition.

Comment: One more reason why assigning every word an official Part of Speech from the 8-crayon box is a totally useless activity. If you know what color it's sposta be, what have you learned about its usage, meaning, and grammar?

Comment: @JohnLawler: As long as you are not committed to cramming it into a single box, I think it can be interesting to explore and draw colourful lines over the boxes.

Comment: OP is flooding the site with elementary questions which show no research effort.

Comment: What the OP learns about its usage, meaning, and grammar is dependent on the answers that are given, which would be better as answers rather than comments.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: When I write 'muffle' I mean 'muffle'. Except for when I type badly or misspell.

Comment: @JohnLawler: so there are labels for more refined functions. Those 8 are a first approximatino and aren't totally useless.

Comment: @Cerberus: I'm with you in considering that it is useful both to study how different words are used and to have cover-terms in most cases for the classes found. However, I believe that traditional classes far too often hinder rather than facilitate analysis. Here, the parenthetical ',as he called it,' is near-synonymous with '(his term)', ',to use his term,' or ',which is what he called it,' though ',which is what he called Harry's British money,' sounds slightly better. It's impossible to match each equivalent structure word-class to word-class.

Comment: As it happens, Geoff Pullum takes up [the case of _than_ and _as_](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2012/11/syntax) in an _Economist_ blog today.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I personally think that, in syntax,  if we only compare a certain construction to a phrase that uses different words, but has roughly the same meaning, that's not always the best approach. Then we look only at the phrase as a whole, not at its internal structure, while syntax should be at a lower level. What the phrase means as a whole is certainly an important argument, but it should not be all. As to word classes, I usually say "x is kind of a pronoun, but it also has certain adjectival properties, and based on y you could also call it a verb", or something like that.

Comment: Unless I’ve missed something recently, there are still very different ideas on how analysable idioms and other fixed expressions should be regarded as being (see Moon at http://www.docstoc.com/docs/123195596/Fixed-Expressions-and-Idioms-in-English-A-Corpus-Based-Approach ): ‘The fundamental question to be addressed is whether a string can be regarded as a unit. … [Some] FEIs [fixed expressions [including] idioms] … cannot be parsed according to normal syntactic rules …’

Comment: When it comes to tricky word-classes: in 'The Handbook of English Linguistics' edited by Aarts & McMahon (p122ff) (available online) is an article looking at whether gradience, multiple membership (your preference) ... are good explanations for the words which all concede are hard to pin down. It does look at various competing theories before, to my mind, disguising a fudge with new nomenclature. At least it recognises that the 'every word used must be classifiable as one of (our!) recognised parts of speech' (Aristotelean) approach is not sacrosanct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it introduces a subordinate clause, I would call it a subordinating conjunction. The clause "as he called it" is a subordinate clause; it contains a finite verb, and is embedded in a larger subordinate clause ("who didn't understand...called it").

The more difficult part of your question is whether this is an adjective clause. The analysis of subordinate clauses varies, and grammarians don't always agree on the correct categorisation for them.

As I understand it, the term "adjective clause" is usually used (often in grammar for students of English as a foreign language) to describe subordinate clauses that modify nouns. These are predominantly relative clauses - clauses that begin with relative pronouns such as "which", "that", and so on:

> The coat that I bought is too big

"that I bought" is a relative clause, acting as a modifier of the noun "coat".

Although "as he called it" doesn't start with a relative pronoun, I would say it still functions to modify the noun phrase ("Muggle money"), so you could make a good case for calling it an "adjective clause".

Comment: Which school is that? Any names? I'm afraid I'm not familiar witht the term _adjective clause_.

Comment: I meant "school" in a general sense - one view of grammar, or one way of looking at grammar, if you like. You'll find the term "adjective clause" in ESL teaching, in particular. From memory, I believe it's usually used of relative clauses modifying nouns, but this special type of "as-clause" could also be interpreted in the same way because it's a subordinate clause that modifies a noun. I've edited my answer to clarify. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Thank you. I can only say I didn't come across it in my ESL training, and haven't come across it since.

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting. I've certainly seen it often-ish in online ESL materials, but not having an ESL background myself my knowledge is second-hand. I wonder whether it's just a way of simplifying the terminology of "relative clause"? If the two are synonymous, of course, "as he called them" would not count as an "adjective clause" because it is not a relative clause.